# What is the `pandas` way to create a column in a dataframe by operating on each row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have an `apply` function that operates on each row in my dataframe. The result of that `apply` function is a new value.  This new value is intended to go in a new column for that row.

So, after applying this function to all of the rows in the dataframe, there will be an entirely new column in that dataframe.

How do I do this in `pandas`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways primarily:

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(my_fxn, axis=1)
```

or

```
df = df.assign(new_column=df.apply(my_fxn, axis=1))
```

If you need to use other arguments, you can pass them to the `apply` function, but sometimes it's easier (for me) to just use a lambda:

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda row: my_fxn(row, global_dict), axis=1)
```

Additionally, if your function can operate on arrays in a vectorized fashion, you could just do:

```
df['new_column'] = my_fxn(df['col1'], df['col2'])
```

Comment: I should've mentioned this before:  my function has two arguments, a row from the `dataframe`, and a global dictionary.  I tried incorporating these like so:  `df['new_column'] = df.apply(my_fxn(row), args=(<global_dictionary>), axis=1)` but it seems to be breaking the global_dictionary up into individual individual K/V pairs.                            As a result it tells me that there are too many arguments.  How do I pass arguments to the `apply` function?

Comment: @DSM D'oh I started down a different path and forgot to clean everything up.

Comment: @Hunle pass the dictionary to the function directly (See the edit)